# Show overlapping data in barplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I generated the bar plot depicting the situation of my data as follows and with the following piece of code:

[image]

> ```
>     mydf
>       Groups    Gene_content    Cases   Intersection
>         25          903         Case1      512
>         25          817         Case2      512
>         20          722         Case1      400
>         20          644         Case2      400
>         15          543         Case1      332
>         15          469         Case2      332
>         10          357         Case1      172
>         10          287         Case2      172
>         5           184         Case1      65
>         5           125         Case2      65
> ```

```
        ggplot(mydf, aes(fill=Cases, y=Gene_content, x=Groups)) +        
        geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", color="black") +        
        geom_text(aes(label=Intersection), vjust=1.6, color="white",       
        position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)+       
        geom_errorbar(aes(y = Intersection, ymin = Intersection,       
        ymax = Intersection), color="Orange",lty=2) +        
        scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")+       
        theme_minimal()
```

What I would like is to: first of all to color with the same color all the bars under the orange line and then let distinguish the bars up to the orange horizontal line as they already are. The common color (yellow) means the "common" elements. Moreover I would to move down the text indicating how many genes are in common. The desired output (as modified with power point) is the following: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could plot the yellow bars and the label text once for each level of `Groups`, rather than twice. Maybe something like this:

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(fill=Cases, y=Gene_content, x=Groups)) +        
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", color="black", width=3) + 
  geom_bar(data=mydf[!duplicated(mydf$Groups), ], stat="identity", 
           aes(Groups, Intersection), fill="yellow", width=3) +
  geom_text(data=mydf[!duplicated(mydf$Groups), ], 
            aes(label=Intersection, y=Intersection - 20), color="black", size=3.5) +       
  # geom_errorbar(aes(y = Intersection, ymin = Intersection,       
  #                   ymax = Intersection), color="Orange",lty=2) +        
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") +       
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The simple thing to do is add another layer of `geom_bar`s on top with height `y=Intersection`. You can move the text down easily by changing the `y` aesthetic in that `geom` call.

```
 ggplot(aes(fill=Cases, y=Gene_content, x=factor(Groups))) +        
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", color="black") +  
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", aes(y = Intersection, group = Cases), 
           fill = "yellow", colour = "black") +  
  geom_text(aes(label=Intersection, y = Intersection), vjust=1.6, color="black",       
            position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)+       
  geom_errorbar(aes(y = Intersection, ymin = Intersection,       
                    ymax = Intersection), color="Orange",lty=2) +        
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")+  
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Or use `nudge_y`.